# Join third table in mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Task: I have three colections: UserPurchases, UserWallet and Currency. UserPurchases have walletId and UserWallet have currencyId.I need to select all userPurchases records, and in one single request join through UserWallet collection to Currency collection and select all data from here by UserWallet.currencyId. My request now looks like:

```
 return UserPurchases.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup:
        {
          from: 'userWallet',
          localField: 'walletId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'wallet'
        }
      },
      { $unwind: "$wallet" },
    ]).toArray();

    Output is:
 [{
        "_id": "5edd0247d6418447bef68738",
        "walletId": 4,
        "brandName": "Adidas",
        "description": "Bye new shoes",
        "amount": -100000,
        "wallet": {
            "_id": 4,
            "userId": 6294,
            "amount": 266667,
            "currencyId": 3
        }
    },]
```

Its select all purchases records and all wallet info. But moroover i need to join to currency collection and get all data from here. Please help me to write this request!)

Comment: You can just use another `$lookup` exactly like how you have done.

Comment: It works. Everything i need is to add wallet collection name in localField statement.
Before 
{
        $lookup:
        {
          from: 'currency',
          localField: 'currencyId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'currency'
        }
      }, - didn't work.

After 
{
        $lookup:
        {
          from: 'currency',
          localField: 'wallet.currencyId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'currency'
        }
      }, - works fine! Thanks for collaboration!)